# Arbitrary donation value using in-app purchases?

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

My users are asking for a way to donate to me via in-app purchases. I could offer different tiers, like $1/$5/$10 managed items. It would be nicer if the user could just input whatever amount they want.

Is there a way to do this? I suppose I could use unmanaged items in increments of $1, but it wouldn't be as nice either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way. You define the price for each in app purchase product, by country.